# Unable to call react hook inside of Formik handleSubmit

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik

I am unable to call `useDispatch` inside of Formik's `handleSubmit` function. I want to dispatch the submitted form values to the redux store when the `submit` button is clicked. How can I do this?

Here is the error - `An unhandled error was caught from submitForm(), [Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.`

Here are snippets of my code

```
const handleSubmit = values => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    console.log(dispatch)
    dispatch({
        type: "ADD_TO_PROFILE",
        payload: {...values}
    })
}
<Formik initialValues={{'dob': ''}} 
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
>
({handleChange, handleBlur, setFieldValue, handleSubmit, values, errors }) => (
 <Button onPress={handleSubmit} />
)}
</Formik>
```

Comment: const dispatch = useDispatch();    <- did you try this outside the handle submit?

Comment: react hooks can be only called from top level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `const dispatch = useDispatch();` outside of `handleSumbit` like this:

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const handleSubmit = values => {
    console.log(dispatch)
    dispatch({
        type: "ADD_TO_PROFILE",
        payload: {...values}
    })
}
<Formik initialValues={{'dob': ''}} 
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
>
({handleChange, handleBlur, setFieldValue, handleSubmit, values, errors }) => (
 <Button onPress={handleSubmit} />
)}
</Formik>
```